# ActionBar Menu Items disappear in NestedFragments

Tags: android, nested, android-actionbar, fragment

Since android 4.2 now support [NestedFragment](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments) , and added it to support v13.

I use this NestedFragment on a classic situation : Create fragmentA that can swipe left and right and consume a majority of the screen space, and insert fragmentB and fragmentC into each fragment page.

My Problem is the MenuItem I create in fragmentB and fragmentC can`t show on Activity`s actionbar.Which before I use NestedFragment , it works well.

Comment: Got any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

got at some point the same problem. If you're using the ActionBarSherlock library this is a small bug. What you basically have to do is to call from your parent fragment from the onCreateOptionsMenu() method the onCreateOptionsMenu() method of the children, something like:

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    getChildFragment().onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

hope this works, let me know.

Cheers.

Comment: getChildFragment() this method doesn't exist in for a fragment. I can't seem to find it anywhere

Comment: so you are talking about this bug right ? https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/828

Comment: Actually you have to use:`getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById()` or `getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag()` to get a child fragment. Then you can call `onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)` on it. Don't forget to check the fragment-instance for being not-null  and `childFragment.isAdded()` before.